# Guidance with piecewise linear data set

Tags: regression, clustering, linear

I have data that looks like:

[image]

As you can see my linear modeling doesn't really work since the y values increase and then stay constant. I want to separate my data for each group into 2 and then perform linear regression on both but the cutoff point is also unknown. How can I go about modelling such phenomena I have no idea?

Comment: If you have such a clear pattern (common staircase and three floors), why not base your analysis right on the picture? I.e., separate regression for the floors, plus one for the staircase.

Comment: I do not know when these floors occur (i.e. there's no deterministic way of finding the number of rows after which the result time is constant).

Answer (score 1):

Try modeling with linear splines where the knots are a part of optimization, so you may need nonlinear regression

Comment: I'll have a look thanks for the tip. Do you have any recommendations for resources?